# Template error: A template that extends another one cannot have a body

Tags: templating

How am I able to use bootstrap in Craft? I created a folder in a templates directory named `_layouts` and inside of that I have `base.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

</html>
```

and this is where i want to include the bootstrap (contact.html)

```
{% extends "_layouts/base" %}
{% macro errorList(errors) %}
{% if errors %}
<ul class="errors">
{% for error in errors %}
            <li>{{ error }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endif %}
{% endmacro %}
{% from _self import errorList %}


<form method="post" action="" accept-charset="UTF-8">
{{ getCsrfInput() }}
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="contactForm/sendMessage">
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="../public/index.php/contact.html">

<h3><label for="fromName">Your Name</label></h3>
<input id="fromName" type="text" name="fromName" value="{% if message is defined %}{{ message.fromName }}{% endif %}">
{{ message is defined and message ? errorList(message.getErrors('fromName')) }}

<h3><label for="fromEmail">Your Email</label></h3>
<input id="fromEmail" type="email" name="fromEmail" value="{% if message is defined %}{{ message.fromEmail }}{% endif %}">
{{ message is defined and message ? errorList(message.getErrors('fromEmail')) }}

<h3><label for="message">Message</label></h3>
<textarea rows="10" cols="40" id="message" name="message">{% if message is defined %}{{ message.message }}{% endif %}</textarea>
{{ message is defined and message ? errorList(message.getErrors('message')) }}

<input type="submit" class = "btn btn-submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

I'm having an error => "A template that extends another one cannot have a body."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `base.html` you need to include a `block` section, so something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
{% block content %}{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

Then in your `contact.html` you need to wrap your main markup in the same `block`, like this:

```
{% extends "_layouts/base" %}
{% macro errorList(errors) %}
{% if errors %}
<ul class="errors">
{% for error in errors %}
            <li>{{ error }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endif %}
{% endmacro %}
{% from _self import errorList %}

{% block content %}
<form method="post" action="" accept-charset="UTF-8">
{{ getCsrfInput() }}
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="contactForm/sendMessage">
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="../public/index.php/contact.html">

<h3><label for="fromName">Your Name</label></h3>
<input id="fromName" type="text" name="fromName" value="{% if message is defined %}{{ message.fromName }}{% endif %}">
{{ message is defined and message ? errorList(message.getErrors('fromName')) }}

<h3><label for="fromEmail">Your Email</label></h3>
<input id="fromEmail" type="email" name="fromEmail" value="{% if message is defined %}{{ message.fromEmail }}{% endif %}">
{{ message is defined and message ? errorList(message.getErrors('fromEmail')) }}

<h3><label for="message">Message</label></h3>
<textarea rows="10" cols="40" id="message" name="message">{% if message is defined %}{{ message.message }}{% endif %}</textarea>
{{ message is defined and message ? errorList(message.getErrors('message')) }}

<input type="submit" class = "btn btn-submit" value="Send">
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

So you are basically saying create an area called `content` in your `base.html` and you want to fill this area with the markup wrapped in the `content` block inside your `contact.html`. You can call the `block` whatever you want, so here we've called it `content`, it doesn't have to be that, but it seems a fairly logical name for it.

You can have more than one block in your `base.html`, if you want. For instance you could have a `header`, `content` and `footer` blocks. All you need to remember is to use the same names inside the template file you are extending the `base.html` from.

More information can be found in the [Twig documentation](https://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/tags/extends.html)

Comment: For what is the "block" property for ? Sorry for asking too much, i'm just starting learning craft cms

Comment: It worked now. Thank you dude. I just want to know the purpose of the block property in craft?

Comment: No problem, glad it's working.

Comment: Steve. what is the purpose of the "block" property? What is it for ?

Comment: They just act as placeholders so you can inject markup into the right place in your template. In the parent template (your `base.html`) you tell it where you want to inject the markup and in your child template `contact.html` you tell it what you want to inject.

Comment: Ok . I got it. Thank tou Steve.

Comment: No worries. It's worth having a read through the Twig docs (I've put a link in the answer). They're fairly short, but pretty well written.

Comment: Steven may i ask you another question ?

Comment: @lanceadriannedelacruz, please consider accepting Steve's answer if it solved your problem. These comments on Stack Exchange aren't intended for chat, please use the Craft Slack group if you want to ask questions and chat more broadly. There are also a [lot of great resources](https://straightupcraft.com/articles/getting-started-with-craft-cms) if you're just getting started with Craft!